# filter items in a list view on sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint

Basically i have created a list by importing a spread sheet which contains username as one of the column. I now want to create a specific view which will show only items in the list only based on currently logged in users how do i do it.

I've tried using [Me] with matching column from the imported spreadsheet but it was not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

[Me] will work for the Field of Type User, while Importing there might be a change in the Type of the Column. Check that.

Comment: Kushek - I do see no problems with the datatype when the spreadsheet is imported completely but it isn't working.